# If they all forget about each other

Tags: it

At the end of the *IT* miniseries if The Losers' Club all begin to forget everything that happened, once again, including each other, does that mean that Bev and Ben will forget how they met? They're supposed to have gotten married at the end of the movie, so that would just kinda make for an awkward relationship.

Comment: I'd have to go back and re-watch, but I think it was just one of those things where you end up forgetting a lot of friends from your youth.  Like, if you're in my age bracket (50, give or take...) and you go back and look at class photos from 2nd grade, how many of those people do you really remember?  Since Ben and Bev were married, they wouldn't forget each other, but the rest of the club would eventually fade from each other's memories.

Comment: I did not see the movie, but in the novel, suddenly all the friends started forgetting really basic things about the others. For example, one character wonders if Stuttering Bill had a stutter, or maybe a handicapped leg that gave him a limp. It was clearly supernatural, since typed pages of recollections were starting to fade into simple white pages. I believe that Bev and Ben would forget how they met, at least in the context of the book. I don't know how faithful the miniseries was to the book.

Comment: I love the movie, never read the book. I just hate the idea of them all forgetting about one another. It's so sad to think that they were all so close and then... nothing. :/ lol. The movie says that Mike and Bill have to start reminding each other what their names are even. All the memories of Derry are just sort of fading away again. I understand that for the sake of forgetting Pennywise it's probably a good thing. I just wish they could remember their friendship... depressing.